# Problem using adafruit-rfm96w Lora transceiver

Tags: python, radio, adafruit, circuitpython

I'm new in programming and for a project I actually need to deal with 2 adafruit-rfm96w to transfer data between 2 Raspberry Pi(one Raspberry Pi 3, and one Pico). But I don't understand how to use the python library adafruit-circuitpython-rfm9x (https://pypi.org/project/adafruit-circuitpython-rfm9x/) and I wired my breadboard exactly as explained in their article about the product (https://learn.adafruit.com/lora-and-lorawan-radio-for-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-wiring) and copy the code they displayed further, but it's not working.
 I'm using python 3.5 but tried with python3.8 to get the same results. I explored several other options, such as using another Lora library like pyLoRa, but it's not fixing my problem. Here is the code I copied :

```
import busio
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction, Pull
import board
import adafruit_rfm9x
CS = DigitalInOut(board.CE1)
RESET = DigitalInOut(board.D25)
spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
while True:
    try:
        rfm9x = adafruit_rfm9x.RFM9x(spi, CS, RESET, 915.0)
        print("RFM detedcted")
    except RuntimeError as error:
        print('RFM9x Error: ', error)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```

### output :

`RFM9x Error:  Failed to find rfm9x with expected version -- check wiring`

It's saying that it's my wiring, but I'm sure it's done right, and therefore I don't know if anyone has a solution to my issue, but help would be appreciated!

Comment: We need to see the wiring (clear photos of all connections). These should be added to your post directly not linked to a 3rd party site.

Comment: This question is lacking detail. You appear to be mixing Python and the custom Adafruit circuit python.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I'll try to update my post qitht pictures as soon as I can have access to it (I'm not at home yet).  And yet I'm more focusing on getting the radio working with the Raspberry Pi 3 which run with a classic python interpreter, I assumed that the library was working the same with both circuitpython and python, isn't it the case?

Comment: Circuitpython is a cut down python designed for microcontrollers. As you haven't posted ANY Pi code (or anything which would run on a Pi) it is impossible to say. I believe it is possible to install a subset of Circuitpython on Pi with another library but never seen anyone use it.

Comment: Oh well, I think you're already giving me a good hint. As I said earlier, I don't have access to any Raspberry Pi now. But as soon as I have access to it, I will try to update my post with some new stuff, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have already enabled SPI ? (using raspi-config)

I would try moving the Chip Select (CS) to another pin (not CE0/CE1) and update your code (*CS = DigitalInOut(board.CE1)*) accordingly

The link below will explain why I am suggesting this : https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/spi-sensors-devices

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I enabled SPI, and I'll try to change the cs line when i will have access to my Raspberry.